# PictureBox Group - How To Align As Grid?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some picture boxes that are added as they are iterated.

Urls are fetched from a database table and looped while adding the PictureBox control with X/Y coordinates.

I figured out after trial and error how to get them aligned in a horizontal row, but issues arise when I want to break the row after 11 pictures, and continue below (Y: first image height + 5 (padding).

I came up with this formula:

```
int rowLimit = 11;
Location = new Point(i > 1 ? 27 * i : 0, i > rowLimit ? i * 27 : 0)
```

Which got me this

[image]

Great. Nearly there.. until I attempt to work at next row below.

**How can I get this as 11 across, and however many left as rows below?**

```
int i = 0;
int rowLimit = 11;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   i++;
   var picture = new PictureBox
   {
      Name = "pictureBox",
      Size = new Size(25, 25),
      Location = new Point(i > 1 ? 27 * i : 0, i > rowLimit ? i * 27 : 0),
      ImageLocation = "https://example.com/" + row["avatar"].ToString()
   };
   Controls.Add(picture);
}
```

If I need to use a flexpanel, please advise.

Any help very appreciated :)

**NOTE:**
*Ignore the broken images, it is expected as some avatars are in fact broken (we deal with this later).*

Comment: [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) with 11 columns, or [FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/flowlayoutpanel-control-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), then [SetFlowBreak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.setflowbreak?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) after 11th control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage another part of winforms, like a table or grid array, but assuming you want to stick with this tool...

Looks like the current Y coordinate of the location will just stack everyting greater than rowLimit vertically. You might consider utilizing integer division to your advantage, like this:

```
Location = new Point(i > 0 ? i * (Size.X + 2) : 0, i / rowLimit > 0 ? i * (Size.Y + 2) : 0)
```

Here, **i / rowLimit** will be 0 when **i** is between 0 and 10, then 1 when **i** is between 11 and 21, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Bang on. I ended up with this - ``Location = new Point(x + (i % columns * w), y + (i / columns * h))``